# Is the answer for the following MATLAB script correct?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a task regarding the `matlab image processing toolbox`. The task is the following:

[image]

My solution to these steps is:

```
I = imread('Ball.jpg');

I1 = imnoise(I, 'salt&pepper', 0.2);

G = rgb2gray(I1);

C = fspecial('Laplacian',h);

imwrite(C, 'clean.jpg');

subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(I1,[]);

subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(C,[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you made quite some mistakes.

First, the image you read is already noisy, as it doesn't specifically say "*add noise to the image*". This makes your second step, `imnoise`, redundant.

Second, by using `fspecial`you are creating a filter. In this case its type is a `Laplacian` filter of a given alpha `alpha` (between 0 and 1). That alone doesn't filter your image. You have to use the function `imfilter` in order to process the image.

```
I = imread('Ball.jpg');

G = rgb2gray(I);

h = fspecial('Laplacian',0.7); % 0.1 is the alpha, try out which one suits your case the most

C = imfilter(G,h);

imwrite(C, 'clean.jpg');

subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(I,[]);

subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(C,[]);
```

Note, that the `Laplacian` filter doesn't have to be the most suitable for you. There are lots of filter types listed in the [MatLab documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html#d120e63166) that you can use. Consider using a Gaussian filter.

Comment: I fixed a wording error in your answer, I hope you don't mind. Furthermore, I would suggest you use a more strong wording than "doesn't have to be the most suitable for you". In fact, this filter does the exact opposite of what the question asks, as it enhances noise. Your Gaussian suggestion is good.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and for the correction @CrisLuengo ! Ill keep them in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is incomplete, for example you don't apply your filter on your noisy picture. Here is an example that might work :

```
%% Load image (I.)
I = imread('Ball.jpg');

%% Convert image into grayscale (II.)
G = rgb2gray(I);

%% Add noise (if 'Ball.jpg' isn't already noisy)
I1 = imnoise(G, 'salt & pepper', 0.2); % NB : imnoise needs the image to be grayscale

%% Create the filter (III.)
C = fspecial('Laplacian');

%% Apply the filter (III.)
IClean = filter2(C,I1);

%% Write the picture in new file  (IV.)
imwrite(IClean, 'clean.jpg');

%% Display images (V.)
subplot(1,2,1), imshow(I1,[]);
subplot(1,2,2), imshow(IClean,[]);
```

Depending on the result, you can validate your idea of an "appropriate spatial domain filter" in question III.

Comment: I would rather use `imfilter` for images than `conv2` or `filter2`. It is a bit more comfortable and also includes some sweet features for slightly complex cases. It is also more efficient for `uint8` values.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I wanted to be as close as possible to the functions proposed by the person who asked the question. I have the feeling that this is an exercise from a homework assignment, so depending on the course he is taking it may seem strange to use an unseen function in class.

Comment: @CrankyBrain Can u please answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570987/which-one-of-the-following-is-correct-code-for-this-matlab