# Which one of the following is an efficient code for this MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, output, matlab-figure

Arrange the 2 given images into one image with image1 (pedestrian) on the left and image2 (no-parking) on the right in one single image. Display the combined single image. 
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Code 1 :-

```
z = imread('NO_PARKING.jpg');

x = imread('PEDESTRIAN.jpg');

r = imresize(z,[500,500]);

c = cat(2,x,r);

imshow(c)
```

Code 2:-

```
[X1,map1]=imread('PEDESTRIAN.jpg');

[X2,map2]=imread('NO_PARKING.jpg');

subplot(1,2,1), imshow(X1,map1)

subplot(1,2,2), imshow(X2,map2)
```

Which of the above codes is correct?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out who to copy your homework exercise form? If you don't understand the code, don't turn it in. It's considered academic fraud where I come from.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Actually I am getting almost the same output for the following code so I am confused as which one would be more efficient.

Comment: You are asking which one is correct. There are 2 ways to interpret that: (1) correct MATLAB code: if you can run it it's correct, so not a meaningful question; or (2) correctly answers the homework question that you copy-pasted at the top of the post. If you want to know which of the two is more efficient, [edit] your question so that it asks that.

Comment: I don't mean to be dismissive. I'd gladly help you learn something here, and I have no problem helping people with their homework if they're actually trying to learn. But I don't want to help people to not do their homework. Because that is the complete opposite of helping people learn.

Comment: @CrisLuengo done

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have already submitted my assignment. And yes I am trying to learn, that is why I have asked this question on Stack Overflow to know which one is more efficient as I have gone with code 1 and my friend has used code 2.

Comment: If you are interested in the more efficient then just time the two codes, whichever is the fastest is the more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The two codes don't do the same thing, so it's not a matter of efficiency. One combines the two images into one, then displays that one image, one just displays the two images in one figure.

If you really want to understand the difference in practice, you may consider:

- Using two images which are different sizes
- Using two images which are the same size but do not have white backgrounds
- A further operation, such as rendering the combined image greyscale or applying a smoothing filter